# Django: prevent manual values on AutoField?

Tags: python, django

Using the default django's `id` attribute, inserting `id=x` in created objects is allowed. Problem is, this breaks the auto-incrementing sequence for subsequent inserts (at least, on postgres, where I use it).

Is there a way to forbid explicitly passing an `id` value to created objects?

Comment: As far as I know not without breaking a lot of things. In fact sometimes constructing an object with a given id is useful. Django implicitly does that when you read items. Finally it is not very "Pythonic" to block things. The idea of Python is: "We are adults, we should behave correctly".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: thanks. Adults make mistakes though, especially when importing data from external sources...

Comment: Well the Django documentation for example explicitly (strongly) advices against overriding the `__init__` constructor (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model). Since a lot of things depend on that. Yes, adults make mistakes, but the "language design" of Python is to allow patching, overriding, etc. Some tricks can be done, but these sometimes tends to cause more harm than good.

Comment: Most Django logic after all will set the `id`. For example, after you make a succesful `.save()`, the returing id is stored in the model. Strictly speaking you can implement a lot of logic to look at the traceback and allow certain setters and others not, but that will require a lot of work, and might fail the other day unexpectedly.